# Type of '1.narrow'

Tags: scala, shapeless

Looking at [Singleton Types](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#singleton-typed-literals):

```
import shapeless._, syntax.singleton._

scala> 1.narrow
res3: Int(1) = 1
```

I attempted to write a function that, given a singleton `1`, i.e. per the above, return `???`:

```
scala> def f(a: Int(1)): Unit = ???
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '(' found.
def f(a: Int(1)): Unit = ???
            ^
<console>:1: error: '=' expected but ')' found.
def f(a: Int(1)): Unit = ???
               ^
```

But it failed to compile.

What is the type of `1.narrow` and how can I use it in a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this type with `shapeless.Witness` syntax:

```
def f(a: Witness.`1`.T): Unit = ???

val a = 1.narrow
f(a) // compiles

val b = 2.narrow
f(b) // type mismatch; found: Int(2) required: Int(1)

val c = 1
f(c) // type mismatch; found: c.type (with underlying type Int) required: Int(1)
```

There is also a [Typelevel Scala](https://github.com/typelevel/scala) compiler branch, that supports literals in types (with the appropriate [compiler flag](https://github.com/typelevel/scala/blob/typelevel-readme/notes/typelevel-4.md#literal-types-pull5310-milesabin)):

```
def f(a: 1): Unit = ???
```